# Compiler Directive for detecting C# 8/nullable reference types

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Is there a compiler directive for C# 8 or detecting if `<nullable>enable</nullable>` is set?

I have a source code only Nuget package that could stand to help with the nullable reference types story. I'd like to conditionally set the `#nullable enable` directive if this is set, such as:

```
#ifdef ICANHASNULLABLE
#nullable enable
#endif
```

and

```
#ifdef ICANHASNULLABLE
string Foo(string? val)
#else
string Foo(string val)
#endif
```

I have a mix of stuff built with the .NET Core 2.1 SDK and am working to bring things to .NET Core 3.1, albeit slowly and not just by flipping a switch. The directive only points to the framework versions, not language version.

Answer (score 4):

Assume you have a multi targeting app. In your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.2;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You could add a conditional `PropertyGroup` specific to `netcoreapp3.1` and have your own constant defined:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp3.1'">
    <DefineConstants>ICANHASNULLABLE</DefineConstants>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can also define your directive based on `<Nullable>`:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Nullable)'=='enable'">
    <DefineConstants>ICANHASNULLABLE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In your code, you could use `ICANHASNULLABLE`:

```
#if ICANHASNULLABLE
void Foo(string? val)
#else
void Foo(string val)
#endif
{
}
```

[Default language version for netcoreapp 3.x is C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version). So any `PropertyGroup` specifically defined for `netcoreapp3.1` in the above example could be considered as specific to C# 8.0 if `LangVersion` is not set.