# C# preprocessor #if check for #nullable enable directive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive, c#-8.0

New versions of C# have a directive to allow object types to be assumed as non-null by default. I have a unity library that's in use by older and newer projects, and I want to support both of them but also still take advantage of the nice nullability feature for newer versions. I tried basically using an `#if` directive that checks for a particular unity version to determine which level of nullability to implement:

```cs
#if UNITY_2021_3_OR_NEWER
#nullable enable
#endif

// define some stuff

#if UNITY_2021_3_OR_NEWER
#nullable restore
#endif
```

However, it seems that even when an `#if` directive evaluates to false, the older C# compilers still read `#nullable enable` and recognize that it's an invalid directive (for that compiler's version). Is there any way to make this work with older versions, maybe through some version check I'm unaware of or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61112738/120955

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiler Directive for detecting C# 8/nullable reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61112738/compiler-directive-for-detecting-c-sharp-8-nullable-reference-types)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior OP basically already has a preprocessor via the Unity version... so there isn't really the need for the answers ProperyGroup .. So I guess here you would simply either use nullables or not ... right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how `UNITY_2021_3_OR_NEWER` gets defined, but yes: if it's defined in a property group like in the answer I linked, then you can just add `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` to that property group, and have the feature turned on or off for the entire project.

Comment: This doesn't work, as I only want it turned on for specific classes, to maintain compatibility with older versions of C#

Comment: Are you using multiple versions of UnityEditor at the same time? Menaing, are you releasing multiple releases built on different engine versions at the same time?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior your answer refers to native C# running under Windows, his question is about Unity and (indirectly) Mono. Unity projects are built differently and `UNITY_2021_3_OR_NEWER` is an engine compiler directive that can run under Linux, Android, iOS, MacOS and so on... that means it's not necessarily compiled using Visual Studio.